# Google sign-in api incorrectly returning invalid_request for youtube brand account

Tags: angular, youtube-api, google-signin

I'm trying to write an angular app to work with the youtube data api. I'm using [this angular wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-signin) to get a google sign-in button. Everything works fine when I select my gmail account in the oauth dialog but when I select my brand account, I get a 403 with the message `{"error": "invalid_request"}` despite the fact that the permissions are shown as granted at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

component typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleSignInSuccess, GoogleSignInFailure } from 'angular-google-signin';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {
    private clientId: string = "copied from google dev console";
    private scope: string = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl " +
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly";
    private title: string = "Hello there!";
    private theme: string = "default";

    onGoogleSignInSuccess(event: GoogleSignInSuccess) {
        let googleUser: gapi.auth2.GoogleUser = event.googleUser;
        let id: string = googleUser.getId();
        let profile: gapi.auth2.BasicProfile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    }

    onFailure(event: GoogleSignInFailure) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

relevant portion of html template:

```
<google-signin [clientId]="clientId"
               [width]="240"
               [height]="50"
               [scope]="scope"
               [longTitle]="true"
               [theme]="theme"
               (googleSignInSuccess)="onGoogleSignInSuccess($event)"
               (googleSignInFailure)="onFailure($event)">
</google-signin>
```

query params sent to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc

```
action=issueToken
response_type=token id_token
login_hint=snip
client_id=snip
origin=http://localhost:8001
scope=openid profile email
ss_domain=http://localhost:8001
```

I've put http://localhost:8001 in the allowed origins. I don't know what's going on with the scope param. This request is being made by google's javascript library. It's exactly the same when it works and the response indicates the scopes I actually requested

Comment: What specific Youtube method are you trying to use again?

Comment: I haven't gotten that far yet. I'm getting an error while trying to get an oauth token